# Mysterious segfault when using stl list

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segfault on the following line:

```
 employees.push_back(Salesperson(id, fname, lname));
```

I don't have the slightest clue what could be causing it. All I'm trying to do is read a text file, put the information from it into a simple class with nothing but getters and setters for each value and a few comparison operators, and put objects of that class into a list. For some reason any time I try to insert into the list, it segfaults. I'm not trying to dereference the end iterator, and it makes no difference which of the lists insertion methods I use. All of them cause the same thing.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ifstream input;
    input.open("sales.txt");
    string s;
    istringstream ss;

    list<Salesperson> employees;

    while (getline(input, s))
    {
        ss.str(s);

        int year, id, sales;
        string fname, lname;

        ss >> year;
        ss >> id;
        ss >> fname;
        ss >> lname;
        ss >> sales;

        getline(input, s);
        ss.str(s);
        float sale;
        OrderedList<float> ol;

        for (int i = 0; i < sales; i++)
        {
            ss >> sale;
            ol.insert(sale);
        }


        list<Salesperson>::iterator it = find(employees.begin(), employees.end(), Salesperson(id, fname, lname));
        if (it == employees.end()) {
            employees.push_back(Salesperson(id, fname, lname));
            employees.back().setSales(employees.back().getSales() + ol);
        } else {
            it->setSales(it->getSales() + ol);
        }

        cout << it->getSales() << endl;

    }
    input.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Salesperson class

```
#ifndef SALESPERSON_H
#define SALESPERSON_H

#include <string>
class Salesperson
{
public:
    //Constructor
    Salesperson(int id, std::string fn, std::string ln)
    {
        employeeID = id;
        fname = fn;
        lname = ln;
    }

    //Gang of Three
    Salesperson(const Salesperson& orig) {*this = orig;}
    ~Salesperson() {}
    void operator=(const Salesperson& orig) 
    {
        employeeID = orig.employeeID;
        fname = orig.fname;
        lname = orig.lname;
        sales = orig.sales;
    }

    //Getters
    int getEmployeeID() {return employeeID;}
    std::string getFname() {return fname;}
    std::string getLname() {return lname;}
    OrderedList<float> getSales() {return sales;}

    //Setters
    void setEmployeeID(int a) {employeeID = a;}
    void setFname(std::string a) {fname = a;}
    void setLname(std::string a) {lname = a;}
    void setSales(OrderedList<float>& a) {sales = a;}

    //Operators
    bool operator<(Salesperson s) {return employeeID < s.employeeID;}
    bool operator==(Salesperson s) {return employeeID == s.employeeID;}
private:
    //Fields
    int employeeID;
    std::string fname, lname;
    OrderedList<float> sales;
};
```

OrderedList cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

template<class type>
OrderedList<type>::OrderedList(const OrderedList<type>& list)
{
    *this = list;
}

template<class type>
void OrderedList<type>::clear()
{
    for (Node<type>* i = head; i != NULL; head = i)
    {
        i = i->getLink();
        delete head;
    }
    size = 0;
}

template<class type>
void OrderedList<type>::remove(type item)
{
    Node<type>* temp = head, *prev = head;
    for (; temp != NULL; prev = temp, temp = temp->getLink())
        if (item == temp->getData()) break;

    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (prev == temp) head = head->getLink();
        else prev->setLink(temp->getLink());
        delete temp;
        size--;
    }
}

template<class type>
void OrderedList<type>::operator=(const OrderedList<type>& list)
{
    clear();
    Node<type>* tail = NULL;
    for (Node<type>* i = list.head; i != NULL; i = i->getLink())
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new Node<type > (i->getData(), NULL);
            tail = head;
        } else
        {
            tail->setLink(new Node<type > (i->getData(), NULL));
            tail = tail->getLink();
        }
    }
    size = list.size;
}

template<class type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const OrderedList<type>& list)
{
    out << "[";
    for (Node<type>* i = list.head; i != NULL; i = i->getLink())
    {
        out << i->getData();
        if (i->getLink() != NULL) out << ", ";
    }
    out << "]";

    return out;
}

template<class type>
void OrderedList<type>::insert(type d)
{
    size++;
    Node<type>* item = new Node<type>(d, NULL);

    Node<type> *i = head, *prev = NULL;
    while (i != NULL)
    {
        if (i->getData() >= d) break;
        prev = i;
        i = i->getLink();
    }

    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        item->setLink(head);
        head = item;
    } else {
        prev->setLink(item);
        item->setLink(i);
    }
}

template<class type>
type OrderedList<type>::get(int k) const
{
    if (k <= 0 || k > size) return NULL;

    Node<type>* i = head;
    type data;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        data = i->getData();
        i = i->getLink();
    }
    return data;
}

template<class type>
OrderedList<type> OrderedList<type>::kLargest(int k) const
{
    OrderedList list;
    Node<type>* i = head;

    if (k <= 0 || k > size) return list;

    for (int j = 0; j < size-k; j++)
    {
        i = i->getLink();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        list.insert(i->getData());
        i = i->getLink();
    }
    return list;
}

template<class type>
OrderedList<type> OrderedList<type>::operator+(const OrderedList& list) const
{
    Node<type>* i = head;
    Node<type>* j = list.head;

    OrderedList newList;
    Node<type>* end;

    for(int k = 0; k < size + list.size; k++)
    {
        if(newList.size == 0 && i->getData() <= j->getData()) {
            newList.head = new Node<type>(i->getData(), NULL);
            end = newList.head;
            i = i->getLink();
            newList.size++;
            continue;
        } else if(newList.size == 0 && i->getData() <= j->getData()) {
            newList.head = new Node<type>(j->getData(), NULL);
            end = newList.head;
            j = j->getLink();
            newList.size++;
            continue;
        }

        if(i == NULL) {
            end->setLink(new Node<type>(j->getData(), NULL));
            end = end->getLink();
            j = j->getLink();
        } else if(j == NULL) {
            end->setLink(new Node<type>(i->getData(), NULL));
            end = end->getLink();
            i = i->getLink();
        } else if(i->getData() <= j->getData()) {
            end->setLink(new Node<type>(i->getData(), NULL));
            end = end->getLink();
            i = i->getLink();
        } else if(i->getData() > j->getData()) {
            end->setLink(new Node<type>(j->getData(), NULL));
            end = end->getLink();
            j = j->getLink();
        }

        newList.size++;
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Comment: Problem with `OrderedList` perhaps? Nothing obviously wrong with the posted code.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong, so the error is probably in either `OrderedList` or `Salesperson`. Do they both follow the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722)? Are they both correctly copyable or movable? Does `OrderedList` manage its resources correctly, especially when you use its `operator+`? Perhaps you could post their definitions.

Comment: please also put the class Salesperson in the description.

Comment: Updated with Salesperson and OrderedList.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably something wrong with the `Salesperson` class. It probably violates the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) or has another, similar, issue. Without seeing its code it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: regarding 2) why can it be executed when employess is empty? the line before pushes an element on the list.

Comment: @TobiasLangner: You are quite right, thanks. Will fix in a moment.

Comment: I've added the Rule of Three definitions to Salesperson and posted it, but I don't see why it needed them.

Comment: @user1884814: Now you've posted the definition, `Salesperson` should follow the "rule of zero" (i.e. just the implicitly declared destructor and copy constructor/assignment), since it doesn't manage any resources other than its own members. The problem is more likely to be in `OrderedList`, which does manage memory in quite a complicated way.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem to my Rule of Three in the OrderedList. I segfault sometimes when I try to use the copy constructor, but I can't tell exactly what conditions cause it.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that your `OrderedList<>` template class is defined largely in a .cpp file - I don't know if that's anything to do with your problem or not.

However, the copy ctor:

```
template<class type>
OrderedList<type>::OrderedList(const OrderedList<type>& list)
{
    *this = list;
}
```

looks to have at least one problem.

Since a copy constructor is responsible for construction an object, the state of members that aren't initialized in the initializer list may not be well defined - particularly base types like pointers. You're trying to delegate the work of the copy to the assignment operator:

```
template<class type>
void OrderedList<type>::operator=(const OrderedList<type>& list)
{
    clear();
    Node<type>* tail = NULL;
    for (Node<type>* i = list.head; i != NULL; i = i->getLink())
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new Node<type > (i->getData(), NULL);
            tail = head;
        } else
        {
            tail->setLink(new Node<type > (i->getData(), NULL));
            tail = tail->getLink();
        }
    }
    size = list.size;
}
```

The first thing that the `operator=()` function does is call `clear()` - but `clear()` relies on the member `head` to be initialized to something sensible, which hasn't happened yet for the object under construction (since `head` is apparently a raw pointer). You should at least have a initialization list item for `head` (and maybe other members of `OrderedList<>`:

```
template<class type>
OrderedList<type>::OrderedList(const OrderedList<type>& list)
    : head(0)
{
    *this = list;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but no luck. I am pretty sure now that the error is something close to this in the OrderedList Rule of Three.

Comment: What does a debugger tell you? Maybe also post the definition of `OrederedList<>`.